# Seeking pure CSS drop-down multi-level menu for ME IE 7+

Tags: css

No JS, please, just pure CSS.   Horizontal, drop down, with sub-menus beyond that

```
item 1    item 2    item 3    item 4
```

hover item 2

```
item 1    item 2    item 3    item 4
          option 1
          option 2
          option 3
```

I want to hover over option 2 and get

```
item 1    item 2    item 3    item 4
          option 1
          option 2  choice 1
          option 3  choice 2
                    choice 3
```

Must work in MS IE 7+ (other browser a bonus, probably a given). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive used [Project7.coms](http://www.projectseven.com/tutorials/navigation/auto_hide/)  css library/technique fairly successfully.  An example of its application can be found on [my small company's website](http://www.akonlinedesign.com) (I apologize for using/ plugging my own site) but it is the only time I've used this library.

Comment: You get the answer, but only becuase I persevered. Neither your own site, nor the link have the sub-menu which I need (and drew with bad ascii art). However, digging around on the link, I found something that does what I want... http://www.projectseven.com/products/menusystems/pmm/demos/examples.htm

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html

Comment: +1 Yes, everyone seems to like it, or base on it (the new SuckerFish). Thanks